# Get Word::Range with specific background colour

Tags: c#, ms-word, range, interop

Suppose I have a text marked like this:

[image]

I want to obtain Ranges that are relevant to each of the coloured block, so the first Range would represent first green block of text, the second one would represent non-coloured group, the third one - the next green text, etc.

Is it a way which is more civilized than just scanning the document symbol by symbol reading each symbol's background property?

Comment: What I usually do is loop through paragraphs to see which ones have the setting I want (in this case the background colour) and only loop through the characters in a paragraph if there is more than one setting in it.

Comment: If you'd paid attention when tagging and use ms-word instead of word you'd have gotten a reaction much sooner... What kind of formatting was used to get the green?